# Cartesian product of finite sets - check my proof

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

> Let $A$ und $B$ be non-empty finite sets. Then the Cartesian product is finite and it holds $$ \vert A \times B\vert = \vert A \vert \cdot \vert B \vert .$$

My proof:

As $A$ und $B$ are finite we have two bijections $f: A \to [m]$ and $g:B\to [n]$, where $[m], [n]$ are the intervalls $[1, ..., m]$ and $[1, ..., n]$ in $\mathbb{N}$, respectively. I define the following function $h: A\times B \to [m\cdot n]$,

$$h(a,b) = f(a)+(g(b)-1)m$$
The function $h$ is injective because it's simply a composition of injective functions (note that $m>0$). Let $y \in [m\cdot n]$ then there exists a $k \in [n]$ such that $(k-1)m < y \leq km$. Also, $y-(k-1)m \in [m]$. So there exist two elements $a \in A $ with $f(a) = y-(k-1)m$ and $b \in B$ with $g(b) = k$. Pluggin them into $h$ yields: $h(a,b) = f(a)+(g(b)-1)m=y-(k-1)m+m(k-1)=y$. As $y$ was arbitrarily chosen, every element of $[m\cdot n]$ has a preimage. Hence, $h$ is bijective so that $A \times B$ is finite and has a cardinality of $\vert A \times B\vert =mn=\vert A \vert \cdot \vert B \vert$.

Is this correct?

Or would you do it differently?

Comment: I wouldn't do it any differently but I would probably only put in half the effort you did.

Comment: From a pure set theory view there is nothing to prove here: the product of cardinals is **defined** as the cardinality of the Cartesian product of representing sets. Finiteness is not relevant. But this is probably from a discrete mathematics course, and we're proving a "counting principle" naively.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, yes, this is more about counting principles than pure set theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't do it any differently but I would probably only put in half the effort you did.

Although it's important to realize that "Assume $A$ has $n$ elements" is, *when* you first walk into a class informal and poorly defined and not acceptable, and that the concept that saying something is finite means "there exists a bijection $f:A \to \mathbb N_n = \{1,....., n\}$" is a formal and precise definition, and that we *have* to use it to prove the must trivial and basic concepts of *counting* which we used to take for granted,... all that is true.  *BUT* that doesn't mean that once we *have* proven and defined those that we can't go *back* to using intuitive terms like "Assume $A$ has $n$ elements".  We can... now that we *know* that "$A$ has $n$ elements" *means* there is a bijection between $A$ and $\{1,....,n\}$.

That point is:

$|A| = n \iff $ there exists a bijection $f:A \to \{1,....,n\}\iff $ we can write $A$ as $A = \{a_1, ...., a_n\}\iff $ "let $a_k = f(k)$" all mean the same thing.

And your proof would have been a lot easier (and fun) to read if you had said:

Let $|A| = m$ and label the elements of $A$ as $\{a_1,....,a_m\}$ and let $|B|= n$ and label the elements of $B$ as $\{b_1,...,b_n\}$ so $A\times B =\{(a_i,b_j)| 1\le i \le m; 1\le j\le n\}$

By the remainder theorem we know that for every $k \in \{0,....,nm -1\}$ there are unique $p,q: 0\le p < m; 0\le q< n$ where $k= q*m + p$.  So for every $k'=k+1  \in \{1,....,nm\}$ there are $i=p+1; j=q+1$ where $k'= (j-1)m + i$.

Thus we may define $c_{(j-1)m + i} =(a_i,b_j)$ to list $A\times B$ as $\{c_1,....., c_{nm}\}$ and we have a bijection between $A\times B$ and $[1,.....,nm]$.